# How can I surround code with my own custom code in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a lot of code with method invocations like:

```
speak(name)
foo(bar, "string", var2)
```

I want to surround the parameter like:

```
speak(check(name))
foo(check(bar), "string", check(var2))
```

I need to do this for many methods and parameters!

How can I create a script/macro on eclipse so that I just click the parameters and press some key and it will surround it with `check()` method?

Comment: How about just using replace, and replace `(name)` with `check(name)`?

Comment: @Plirkee `(name)` is just an example, it not always like this. I've edited the question to make that clear

Comment: I would go outside of eclipse for such a task. you can write a script in your favorite script lang and scan the file system. you can even write it in java if that suit you. you can use regular expression for this

Comment: use @Plirkee suggestion with some regex

Comment: As I see it, It is either what GhostCat has suggested or you should do some script writing (e.g. `python`) in order to process all your files, use  regular expressions, substitute strings   etc...

Answer (score 2):

A non-answer: don't do this. Instead of changing

```
speak(name)
```

to

```
speak(check(name))
```

change it to

```
speakWithCheck(name)
```

Meaning: either simply use the refactoring capabilities of eclipse to change the method name; and all invocations to `speakWithCheck()`; or at least add that **new** method that clearly describes what it is doing instead of **polluting** many many places in your source code like this.

You can then declare `speak()` to be @deprecated; and over time get rid of that method altogether.

The fact that you **can** somehow make such "mass manipulation" of code doesn't mean that it is a good idea.

Comment: The problem is that its a bit more complicated and there isn't just one method `speak()` there are 200+ different method with different number of parameters and parameter types. it's a last resort kind of hack

Comment: Then why don't you *add* that check() call into speak() ?

Comment: I agree with this approach, as I find it hard to read if there are many encapsulated calls. If this is user input maybe there is a way to validate their input before it reaches speak(). Edit: moreover, changing a method's name is supported by Eclipse (it will change the method name in all the callers).

Answer (score 0):

There are several plugins that support macro function (recording of keyboard clicks, play with a special key combo) check the eclipse marketplace https://marketplace.eclipse.org/category/free-tagging/keyboard-macros